# Error de complilacion al rellenar formulario web desde excel con Vba

Tags: web, vba

Hola a todos me gustaria que alguien me ayudar con esto Estoy intentando rellenar una pagina de web y me da un error de compilacion "no coinciden los datos" en esta linea de codigo

apiShowWindow IEexp.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

copio todo el codigo

```
Declare PtrSafe Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
            (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Global Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2

Sub PASAR_DATOS()

    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
    Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
    IEexp.Visible = True


   IEexp.navigate "http://sotermica.es/mapadecorte/"
    apiShowWindow IEexp.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE
    
    IEexp.document.getElementById("v1").Value = Range("a4").Value
    IEexp.document.getElementById("v2").Value = Range("b4").Value
    IEexp.document.getElementById("v3").Value = Range("c4").Value
    IEexp.document.getElementById("sendBtn").Click


    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal declarado el navegador. Hay que declararlo como objeto.
Cambia:

```
Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
Set IEexp = New InternetExplorer
```

Por:

```
Dim IEexp As Object
Set IEexp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

Saludos.